# 'myFunction is not a function', JS & Google Maps v 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Hello I cannot figure out why I get this error.

I've got a list with inputs which values contain lat/long/name/address.

Printing the markers on the map works fine, using the infowin workED fine, till I realized that it only openend the same info in all windows. Soo, obviously I needed to attach `this` (the marker i just clicked) to the eventListner.

But, when doing this I get an error saying `view.createMarkerHTML is not a function`.

Question: What do I do to attach the right info to be open, on the right marker?

```
view = {
        map: {
            init: function init (){
                view.map.initMap();
            },

            initMap: function initMap() {
                if(navigator.geolocation) {
                    function hasPosition(position) {
                        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),     
                        myOptions = {
                            zoom: 12,
                            center: point,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        },   
                        mapDiv = document.getElementById("map"),
                        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);                        
                        view.map.handleMarkers(map);

                    }                    
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(hasPosition);

                } 
            },


            handleMarkers: function handleMarkers(map) {
                var list = $('#pois input'),
                    l = list.length,
                    i = 0, lat = '', long = '', marker = {}, theName = '', address = '', info = {};



                 for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                    info = $(list[i]).val().split('|');
                    lat = parseFloat(info[0], 10);
                    long = parseFloat(info[1], 10);
                    theName = info[2];
                    address = info[3];

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                        map: map,
                        icon: icon
                    }); 



                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        currentMarker = this;view.map.createMarkerHTML(map, theName, address);
                    });                  
                 } 
            } ,

             createMarkerHTML: function createMarkerHTML(map, theName, address) {

                var contentString =
                    '<div id="gMapInfoWin">' +
                        '<h1>' + theName + '</h1>' +
                        '<ul>' +
                            '<li>' + address + '</li>' +
                        '</ul>' +
                    '</div>'
                ;

                currentMarker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentString
                });

                currentMarker.infowindow.open(map, currentMarker);
            } 
       }
};
```

Comment: I don't see `view` defined anywhere, the question's *very* hard to answer without this.  For kicks though, try `view.map.createMarkerHTML(map, theName, address);`

Comment: Nick, u should post that as an answer since that is the answer.

Comment: Of course it's view.map.function() I totally forgot about the map object. It's easy to stare yourself blind on your own code hey. Super thanks for that.

Comment: However, the main problem still remains tho, I'll change my code so it's easier to understand, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                    info = $(list[i]).val().split('|');
                    lat = parseFloat(info[0], 10);
                    long = parseFloat(info[1], 10);

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                        map: map,
                        icon: icon
                    }); 

                   marker.theName = info[2];
                   marker.address = info[3];

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        currentMarker = this;   
                        m_name = this.theName;    
                        m_address = this.address        
                        view.map.createMarkerHTML(map, m_name, m_address);
                    });                  
                 }
```

marker.theName = info[2];
 marker.address = info[3];
currentMarker = this;
m_name = this.theName;
 m_address = this.address

... is the soulution!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you use a closure to keep the values of your variables set in the loop ?

```
(function(theName, address) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        currentMarker = this;view.map.createMarkerHTML(map, theName, address);
    });
}(theName, address));
```

You could even add your marker in parameter instead of using `currentMarker`

Comment: part of the code that u cant see is a closure, but thanks anyways

Comment: Hm... but even if this code is in a closure... I think you need another one anyway to save the values of your variables `theName` and `address`. Have you tried it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll wager that it's a scoping issue.  Not having access to your libs I can't be sure that this will work, but try replacing:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    currentMarker = this;view.map.createMarkerHTML(map, theName, address);
});
```

with this:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 
                                'click', 
                                createClickListener(  this, 
                                                      map, 
                                                      theName, 
                                                      address ) );
```

and then add this function somewhere else in the program:

```
function createClickListener( cm, map, theName, address )
{
    return function() {
        currentMarker = cm;
        view.map.createMarkerHTML(map, theName, address);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but im using google.maps.event.addListener() which is standard in google maps v 3

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't mean that it couldn't be a scoping issue.